# Where does Pester's Invoke-Pester reside?

Tags: powershell, code-coverage, pester

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Code-Coverage) it should be possible to measure code coverage using Pester.

```
PS C:\path\to\codeCoverage> Invoke-Pester .\CoverageTest.Tests.ps1 -CodeCoverage .\CoverageTest.ps1

Invoke-Pester : The term 'Invoke-Pester' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Pester .\CoverageTest.Tests.ps1 -CodeCoverage .\CoverageTest.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Pester:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [this documentation](http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/pester-unit-testing-for-powershell/) it was clear that the Pester module needs to be imported before running `Invoke-Pester`

```
PS C:\path\to\codeCoverage> Import-Module "C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\lib\pester.3.1.1\tools\Pester.psm1"
PS C:\path\to\codeCoverage> Invoke-Pester .\CoverageTest.Tests.ps1 -CodeCoverage .\CoverageTest.ps1
Executing all tests in 'C:\Users\r\Desktop\codeCoverage\CoverageTest.Tests.ps1'
Describing Demonstrating Code Coverage
 [+] Calls FunctionOne with no switch parameter set 1.8s
 [+] Calls FunctionTwo 287ms
Tests completed in 2.09s
Passed: 2 Failed: 0 Skipped: 0 Pending: 0

Code coverage report:
Covered 60.00 % of 5 analyzed commands in 1 file.

Missed commands:

File             Function    Line Command
----             --------    ---- -------
CoverageTest.ps1 FunctionOne    5 return 'SwitchParam was set'
CoverageTest.ps1 FunctionTwo   16 return 'I do not'
```

Comment: And in my case I removed the built-in Pester 3.4 that comes with Windows.  There's a script for that https://gist.github.com/nohwnd/5c07fe62c861ee563f69c9ee1f7c9688